# Unable to access the android library project ".so" file in host application in android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have written one android library application which has some ".so" file and corresponding java class which consist of java native methods.

Now added this library project to another android project and try yo call the methods which are there in library ".so" file.

But when i run the app i am getting the error saying unable to load the ".so" file.

Here is the code:

Library app code:

SampleJniBridge.java

```
 public class SampleJniBridge {
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("sample");//here there is a so file named with libsample.so in libs
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError use) {
       Log.e("Testing","JNI:WARNING: Could not load libsample.so");
    }
}

public static native boolean init();
public static native boolean finit();
  }
```

In host application i have added the above library project and tried to use the methods

```
    SampleJniBridge.init();
```

I am getting the error saying "JNI:WARNING: Could not load libsample.so".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself found the solution.

Looks like that i did some mistake in loading the library in my application dependent project.

But it is concluded that we can load the ".so" file in library project also.

Comment: Can u please guide me that how to use .so files in Android library project? I am using .so files of SQLcipher in library project and when add this jar in main android project, i m getting UnsatisfiedLinkError exception